# How do I get the currently connected network interface name using Cocoa or Foundation?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, networking, core-foundation

I need to know the network interface name of the currently connected network interface, as in **en0**, **lo0** and so on.

Is there a Cocoa/Foundation function that is going to give me this information?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can cycle through network interfaces and get their names, IP addresses, etc.

```
#include <ifaddrs.h>
// you may need to include other headers

struct ifaddrs* interfaces = NULL;
struct ifaddrs* temp_addr = NULL;

// retrieve the current interfaces - returns 0 on success
NSInteger success = getifaddrs(&interfaces);
if (success == 0)
{
    // Loop through linked list of interfaces
    temp_addr = interfaces;
    while (temp_addr != NULL)
    {
      if (temp_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET) // internetwork only
      {
        NSString* name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name];
        NSString* address = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)temp_addr->ifa_addr)->sin_addr)];
        NSLog(@"interface name: %@; address: %@", name, address);
      }

      temp_addr = temp_addr->ifa_next;
    }
}

// Free memory
freeifaddrs(interfaces);
```

There are many other flags and data in the above structures, I hope you will find what you are looking for.

Comment: Nice, will check this out and report back here.

Answer (score 3):

Since iOS works slightly differently to OSX, we had luck using the following code based on Davyd's answer to see the names of all available network interfaces on an iPhone: ([also see here for full documentation on ifaddrs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html))

```
#include <ifaddrs.h>

struct ifaddrs* interfaces = NULL;
struct ifaddrs* temp_addr = NULL;

// retrieve the current interfaces - returns 0 on success
NSInteger success = getifaddrs(&interfaces);
if (success == 0)
{
    // Loop through linked list of interfaces
    temp_addr = interfaces;
    while (temp_addr != NULL)
    {
            NSString* name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name];
            NSLog(@"interface name: %@", name);

        temp_addr = temp_addr->ifa_next;
    }
}

// Free memory
freeifaddrs(interfaces);
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can also utilize `if_indextoname()` to get available interface names. Here is how **Swift** implementation would look like:

```
public func interfaceNames() -> [String] {

    let MAX_INTERFACES = 128;

    var interfaceNames = [String]()
    let interfaceNamePtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.alloc(Int(IF_NAMESIZE))
    for interfaceIndex in 1...MAX_INTERFACES {
        if (if_indextoname(UInt32(interfaceIndex), interfaceNamePtr) != nil){
            if let interfaceName = String.fromCString(interfaceNamePtr) {
                interfaceNames.append(interfaceName)
            }
        } else {
            break
        }
    }

    interfaceNamePtr.dealloc(Int(IF_NAMESIZE))
    return interfaceNames
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ported the sample code of @ambientlight to iOS 13:

```
public func interfaceNames() -> [String] {

        let MAX_INTERFACES = 128;

        var interfaceNames = [String]()
        let interfaceNamePtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.allocate(capacity: Int(Int(IF_NAMESIZE)))
        for interfaceIndex in 1...MAX_INTERFACES {
            if (if_indextoname(UInt32(interfaceIndex), interfaceNamePtr) != nil){
                let interfaceName = String(cString: interfaceNamePtr)
                interfaceNames.append(interfaceName)
            } else {
                break
            }
        }

        interfaceNamePtr.deallocate()
        return interfaceNames
    }
```

**Most likely leaking memory - Use with caution.**

Output:

```
▿ 20 elements
  - 0 : "lo0"
  - 1 : "pdp_ip0"
  - 2 : "pdp_ip1"
  - 3 : "pdp_ip2"
  - 4 : "pdp_ip3"
  - 5 : "pdp_ip5"
  - 6 : "pdp_ip4"
  - 7 : "pdp_ip6"
  - 8 : "pdp_ip7"
  - 9 : "ap1"
  - 10 : "en0"
  - 11 : "en1"
  - 12 : "en2"
  - 13 : "ipsec0"
  - 14 : "ipsec1"
  - 15 : "ipsec2"
  - 16 : "ipsec3"
  - 17 : "awdl0"
  - 18 : "utun0"
  - 19 : "utun1"
```