# How to get network interface info (e.g. 'en0') on iOS?

Tags: ios

Some of the iOS API's (e.g. DNS-SD) provide info by giving you the int index of a network-interface (e.g. "1").

But Apple's own API for querying network-interfaces - SystemConfiguration.framework - has those API calls blocked/deleted/MIA for iOS (they're all marked as "OS X only").

How do you query these interfaces on iOS?

(FYI: use-case is: "With iOS, Apple officially requires you to manually inspect interfaces returned from DNS-SD requests to decide which ones are bluetooth versus wifi. Apple gives us an interface index, but no further info")

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why the SystemConfiguration calls are missing from iOS, but it seems you can use the standard ifaddrs.h calls to get some of the core info, as per this SO answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13279757/153422

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can get network interface name of iOS device with the following API.

- NWPathMonitor :
  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/nwpathmonitor

Normal iOS device has the network interface,

- Wi-Fi : "en0"
- Cellular : "pdp_ip0"

But iOS devices I use for development rarely have an "en2" Wi-Fi network interface.