# NSNetService Resolve ipv6 that can not make an http request on it

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6.1, ios8.1

Recently, i was facing a problem while resolving `NSNetService`.

I was published an `NSNetService` with type `_http._tcp.`, to be just like an http server.
Other wise, on another device, i was start searching for this service, and it will find it.

After finding it, i was apply `resolveWithTimeout` on it.

While resolving, sometimes i was get only ipv6, that i can't make an HTTPRequest using `NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: queue: completionHandler:` on it.

How can i apply and HTTPRequest on url contains ipv6 ?
How can i deal with that problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're building a string like `http://{IP}:{port}/` based on the information provided in `NSNetService`. And it works fine for an IPv4 address, the resulting string is like `http://192.168.1.8:8080/`.

However, IPv6 addresses use colons as a separator (instead of periods), so the same code generates a string like `http://fe80::e31:db5a:0089:98ba:8080/`, and the resulting address is incorrect. First, you need to wrap the address in square brackets: `http://[fe80::e31:db5a:0089:98ba]:8080/`. Second, `fe80::/64` (as in the example) addresses are link-local and can be assigned to each IPv6-supporting interface, so you need to also provide the interface to use, e.g. `http://[fe80::e31:db5a:0089:98ba%25en0]:8080/` where `%25` is an encoded percent symbol and `en0` is the interface name to use.

To sum up, you need to build different strings for IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. Speaking of which, there are Apple's recommendations:

> As a rule, you should not resolve a service to an IP address and port number unless you are doing something very unusual.
>   – [Connecting to a Bonjour Service by IP Address](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/NSNetServiceProgGuide/Articles/ResolvingServices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001078-SW4)

Try to use this URL string if possible: `http://{hostname}:{port}/`, you won't need those extra IP address manipulations.

Comment: I tried to find how I can find interface name - but I couldn't, can you please point me into right direction? Like how I know if its en0 or en1 and etc.

Comment: @CherpakEvgeny AFAIK `en0` is the standard interface name for WiFi in iOS. you can also iterate through available interfaces: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13279757/635603

Comment: see my answer bellow

Comment: Thanks a lot man , i was searching for some days for this solution! You are the best !

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I end up using... it correctly translates address into URL including the interface:

```
NSString *          result = nil;
char                host[NI_MAXHOST];
char                service[NI_MAXSERV];
int                 err;

err = getnameinfo(address.bytes, (socklen_t) address.length, host, sizeof(host), service, sizeof(service), NI_NUMERICHOST | NI_NUMERICSERV);
if (err == 0) {
    struct sockaddr_storage *sockaddr = (struct sockaddr_storage *)address.bytes;
    if (sockaddr->ss_family == AF_INET6) {
        result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%s]:%s", host, service];
    } else if (sockaddr->ss_family == AF_INET) {
        result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s:%s", host, service];
    }
}
```