# Bonding cellular and Wi-Fi connections in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I would like to combine the wi-fi and cellular network interfaces to increase the bandwidth for video uploads in one of my iOS applications. For example, if I use the 3G connection having 500KBPS and WIFI having 1MBPS, combined should have 1.5MBPS.

So far I was able to list out the names of network interfaces as mentioned here : [How do I get the currently connected network interface name using Cocoa or Foundation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279220/how-do-i-get-the-currently-connected-network-interface-name-using-cocoa-or-found/13279757#13279757).

As an example, the "Dejero Live+ Mobile App" was able to do this: https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/dejero-live+-mobile-app/id517063387.

I have also looked through the forums specified for Android: https://sites.google.com/site/lotuseaterarpit/news/3g4gwififorandroidconcurrently

Have also gone through this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20061655/simultaneous-use-of-cellular-and-wifi-ad-hoc-in-ios-7 as well but couldn't understand what needs to be done.

Please suggest how can we do in iOS? Any information would be helpful.

Thanks,
Shiva.

Comment: This is not possible in current iOS SDK.

Comment: @rckoenes : Have you seen the Dejero app? ( https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/dejero-live+-mobile-app/id517063387) which is there in the appstore, they are quoting as they did bonding. Please check it once.

Comment: Well there is not option for this in the current SDK, you might be abel to do with some socket bound to some network interface. But I'm not sure whether that is possible. Also I don't seen any mention fin the app you linked to about bounding.

Comment: You can see it in the Key features the first point says :
• High-quality video over bonded cellular and Wi-Fi connections

Comment: Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Of course you **can**!

1. You should use native C code.
2. You should use bind() call specifying IP address per **interface**.
3. Due to (2) you should create a lot of sockets.
4. You should create new sockets and garbage collect old ones when you receive Reachability notifications.
5. You should enumerate current interfaces each time network conditions change.

Some insights you could find in my gist:
https://gist.github.com/avesus/fdb465b60a4f5204845c

Comment: Thank you Avesus. Is there a way with HTTP rather than binding sockets? As I read it can be done at three layers in the net-
work stack such as TCP (MPTCP), sockets, and the HTTP layer (http://varun-anand.com/publications/Thesis.pdf). I would like to do this at HTTP layer.

Comment: No, you definitely should learn BSD sockets programming, flow TCP connections to your 3rd-party HTTP client. You should write code by your hands.

Comment: Also, my gist example is about UDP, but for TCP all things are the same. Just look at any HTTP client library on GitHub. There is no smart API. There is no simple code. Apple and Google wants you to use that IP which they give you! Strange conspiracy theory, right? (On Android, they should make a special Java call to ConnectivityManager to set mobile priority! WHAT?!!) So, things go poorer year to year all because of bad lazy programmers around us.