# How to fetch the routing table details on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking

is there a way we can fetch routing table information on iOS? We can get network interface details surely as explained in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279220/how-do-i-get-the-currently-connected-network-interface-name-using-cocoa-or-found/13279757#13279757). Is there a way we can utilize it to get routing table details on iOS (The MAC OSX equivalent is running the command `netstat -nr`)?

I see the app "[System Guard](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/system-guard-network-data/id734858363?mt=8)" doing exactly this. So there must be some app-store-approved method that allows to print the routing table.

Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check out my repo: https://github.com/jianpx/ios-cabin/tree/master/RouteTableManager

Description：

## RouteTableManager

- flaw: destination property can not display netmask, for example, `netstat -r` sometimes would display `10.1.1/32`. If you have good idea to implement the netmask, please let me know and send me a pull request.
- sources files are:RouteTableManager.h/m and RouteRecord.h/m
- import "RouteTableManager.h"
- `[RouteTableManager getAllRoutes]` to get all routes, every route record's property is in RouteRecord.h
- `[RouteTableManager formatRouteTable]` can get route table string like unix command `netstat -r`, e.g.

`Destination       Gateway            Flags     Refs   Use     Mtu     Netif   Expire

default           10.250.174.1       UGSc      189    0       1500    en0     0

10.62.0.0         10.62.2.35         UGSc      11     0       1500    tun0    0

10.62.2.35        10.62.2.35         UH        2      0       1500    tun0    0

10.63.23.0        10.62.0.1          UGSc      1      0       1500    tun0    0

10.63.58.0        10.62.0.1          UGSc      1      0       1500    tun0    0

10.250.174.135    b8.e8.56.6.be.38   UHLWIi    1      1       16384   lo0     0

218.107.55.89     10.250.174.1       UGSc      1      0       1500    en0     0

224.0.0.0         link #5            UCSm      2      0       1500    en0     111

224.0.0.251       1.0.5e.0.0.fb      UHLWIm    1      0       1500    en0     0   255.255.255.255   link #5            UCS       1      0       1500    en0     1343`

Answer (score -1):

An option would be to decompile System Guard to get the command.

Comment: Any pragmatic links for reverse engineering/ decompiling ios binaries?