# Is there a way in IOS to find the types for all network interfaces?

Tags: ios, networking

In IOS, the reachability API provides the network type information (Cellular or Wifi) for the current active network interface. 
Is there a way to find the types for all network interfaces?

Comment: I originally marked this as a duplicate, but your question is actually slightly different.  Look at the highest voted answer for this question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279220/how-do-i-get-the-currently-connected-network-interface-name-using-cocoa-or-found/13279757#13279757 and you'll see how to enumerate all the network interfaces on iOS.

Comment: That only lists the available network interfaces but does not give us the type information for each interface. I need to find out which is Wifi and which is Cellular. I guessed some from the name. "enX" is typically for Wifi (or Ethernet), "pdp_ipX" is typically for Cellular. But I also saw interface names like "ipsecX".