# NetworkExtension VPN iOS change cellular to Wifi

Tags: ios, swift, wifi, vpn, networkextension

I'm writing a NetworkExtensions app that manages a VPN. What's the correct way to manage the VPN when handover from wifi to cellular and vice versa occurs?

At the moment I'm detecting network changes with reachability (https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift) and using NEVPNStatus.reasserting. That's the best way?

thanks!

Comment: Are you able to solve this ?

Comment: @Oriol Mari, did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a network interface watcher for this purpose.

It should initially get [current active interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13279757/1492173) (excluding `utun`), and then fire every second to get active interfaces again. Compare the ordered collections of "old" and "new" interfaces, the watcher can tell, whether or not user switches between WiFi and Cellular.

> NOTE: You might also find it useful to monitor SSID name of current WiFi network too.